# HTML tags in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that stores some texts in mysql database.
I have another page that will pull that information/data out of the mysql database.

here is the issue:

when i store the texts in mysql database, they get stored like so:

```
hello world.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;i want to go out.&lt;br&gt;
```

when I output the mysql result on the page, i get this:

```
hello world.<br><br>i want to go out.<br>
```

the `<br>` tags have no affects as the entire texts will be displayed in 1 line instead of breaking the line where the `<br>` tags are! and Also they are HTML tags, but they also display on my HTML page!

I have used `strip_tags();` and it didn't have any affect in it.

could someone please help me out with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Look at nl2br function

Comment: You appear to be calling `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` somewhere between the data being sent by the user, and you saving it in the database. This is a (sadly) common trait among over-zealous escapers.

Comment: Thats because the browser interprets the &gt and &lt as "< and >" but your code has no sense what that &lt and &gt is. Tip: You should change something in your saving data so it gets saved like "<br> instead of &lt;br&gt;

Comment: Where does the stored data come from?  If it's arbitrary untrusted user input, then you *must not* output it as HTML (or else you will be vulnerable to XSS attack).

Comment: @Daan, nl2br function is only for when you are changing 1 string I think. my strings are dynamic and they come from mysql database and also nl2br won't help for the mysql wonky HTML tags issue that i mentioned above.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Actually, it's not so common really. A majority of developers insert the data *as is* into the database

Comment: @user3592614 Did you read my comment? You have to change something in your saving algorithm.

Comment: @asprin: He said "common trait **among over-zealous escapers**".  The developers to whom you refer are probably not the same set as those to whom Niet was referring.

Comment: @asprin Yes... that's what you're supposed to do (using prepared queries).

Comment: @eggyal Ah right. That I agree upon

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, your comment pointed me in the right direction. its solved now.

Comment: You are encoding the HTML with htmlentities or htmlspecialchars. Instead of encoding the HTML before inserting into the database you should be calling this when you are getting the HTML out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `html_entity_decode()` to decode the output you have. 
[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is the doc of this function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should change your saving algorithm to save the text as-is in the database. Currently you are calling `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` on the text, before you input it into the database.

To insert the text as-is securely, you can for example use PDO and prepared statements:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO(...);
$st = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO reviews (id, comment) VALUES (null, ?)');
$st->execute(array($_POST['comment_text']));
```

Whatever `$_POST['comment_text']` contains, the generated SQL statement is secure.

To prevent malicious HTML code you should call `htmlspecialchars` on **outputting** the values like

```
<?php
$st = $db->query('SELECT * FROM reviews');
foreach ($st as $s) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($s['comment']);
}
```